# Spring Solr Spell Checker Component to match closet word

Tags: solrj, solr4, spring-data-solr

I am new to Solr. I am using spring 3.x and Solr 4.6

Below is my `Schema.xml`

```
<schema name="customer_site_address" version="1.5">

<fields>
    <field name="id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="name" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="number" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="address" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="city" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="state" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="zipcode" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="country" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="latlng" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</fields>

<!-- Configure unique key -->
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<copyField source="name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="number" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="address" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="city" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="state" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="zipcode" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="country" dest="text"/>

<types>
    <!-- Long -->
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
    <!-- String -->
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
    <!-- Text -->
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <!-- Configures the analysis done at the index phase -->
        <analyzer type="index">
            <!-- Uses word break rules of the Unicode Text Segmentation algorith 
                when splitting text into words. -->
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <!-- <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/> -->
            <!-- <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/> -->
            <!-- Removes words found from stopwords.txt file. This filter is case 
                insensitive. -->
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />

            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="'" replacement="" replace="all" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                 generateWordParts="1" 
                 generateNumberParts="1" 
                 catenateWords="1" 
                 catenateNumbers="1" 
                 catenateAll="0" 
                 splitOnCaseChange="1"
            />
            <!-- Transforms text to lower case -->
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />

            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
        </analyzer>
        <!-- Configures the analysis done at the query time -->
        <analyzer type="query">
            <!-- Uses word break rules of the Unicode Text Segmentation algorith 
                when splitting text into words. -->
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <!-- <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/> -->
            <!-- <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/> -->
            <!-- Removes words found from stopwords.txt file. This filter is case 
                insensitive. -->
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <!-- Applies synonyms found from the synonyms.txt file. -->
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"
                ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
            <!-- Transforms text to lower case -->
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />

            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
</types>
```

Below is `SearchComponent` in `solrconfig.xml`

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>

<lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">default</str>
    <str name="field">text</str>
    <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
    <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
    <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
    <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
    <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
    <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
    <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
    <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
</lst>

<!-- a spellchecker that can break or combine words.  See "/spell" handler below for usage -->
<lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
    <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>      
    <str name="field">text</str>
    <str name="combineWords">true</str>
    <str name="breakWords">true</str>
    <int name="maxChanges">10</int>
</lst>
```

Below is `RequestHandler` in `solrconfig.xml`

```
<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="df">text</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
    <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>       
    <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
    <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
    <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>         
</lst>
<arr name="last-components">
  <str>spellcheck</str>
</arr>
```

Now, when i call `/spell` for a city `frgo` which generates below query string.

```
qt=/spell&spellcheck.q=frgo&spellcheck=true&mm=100%
```

I am getting following alternatives : **(current result)**

```
[f r, f r g, fargo, f r g o, farg]
```

It should give me : **(expected)**

```
[fargo]
```

Another case when i enter `wset frgo` which generates below query string

```
qt=/spell&spellcheck.q=wset+frgo&spellcheck=true&mm=100%
```

I am getting following alternatives : **(current result)**

```
[w s, w s e, west, w s e t, wert, f r, f r g, fargo, f r g o, farg]
```

It should give me : **(expected)**

```
[West, West Fargo]
```

I did apply some solutions found via google but i think i am making mistake to config.
I have also tried with `solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory` and `solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` for `index` and `query` analyzer.

Please guide me.

**EDIT:**

I removed below filter and it worked at some point.

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
```

Now if i enter `wset frgo` which generates below query string

```
qt=/spell&spellcheck.q=wset+frgo&spellcheck=true
```

I am getting following alternatives : **(current result)**

```
[west, fargo, farg]
```

It should give me : **(expected)**

```
[west, fargo, west fargo]
```

Still `West Fargo` is not returned.

Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: A word in a closet??

Answer (score 0):

Check your field in Solr Admin if West Fargo is index.

Comment: I am using Embedded Solr Server

Answer (score 0):

Change this config in you wordbreak spellchecker config

```
<str name="breakWords">true</str>
```

to

```
<str name="breakWords">false</str>
```

or you can completely remove the wordbreak spellchecker from "/spell" handler.